# Convert string to date - roman month

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format

I have following string: "05 X 02". How can i convert it to date? I don't want to convert it to string "05 10 02" and then to date. Is it possible?

Thanks for help.

So far i was trying use

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd M/L yy");
```

But it doesn't work. Also trying use DateTimeFormatterBuilder, but here I'm completely lost.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Please show what you've tried so far and explain what the specific problem is. Also, how are you planning on by bypassing a format that `Date` can actually read? What's the reason for this seemingly arbitrary requirement?

Comment: What parsing are you trying to use - `SimpleDateFormat`? Have you tried `SimpleDateFormat.setDateFormatSymbols` and supplying a set of format symbols where the month names are `I`, `II` etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change default format symbols to have romanic numbers for months

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance();

final String[] romanMonths =  {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII"};
symbols.setMonths(romanMonths);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy", symbols);

System.out.println("My date " + formatter.parse("05 X 02"));
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormatSymbols.html) is a nice tutorial about how to have custom formatting symbols.

You can choose to change either short months via `setShortMonths()` or full months via `setMonths()`

**UPDATE:** Here is a version with [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) from JDK8

```
static final ImmutableMap<Long, String> ROMAN_MONTHS = ImmutableMap.<Long, String>builder()
                .put(1L, "I").put(2L, "II").put(3L, "III").put(4L, "IV").put(5L, "V")
                .put(6L, "VI").put(7L, "VII").put(8L, "VIII").put(9L, "IX").put(10L, "X")
                .put(11L, "XI").put(12L, "XII").build();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                    .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, ROMAN_MONTHS)
                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
                    .toFormatter();

System.out.println("My date " + formatter.parse("5 X 2012"));
```

Comment: I added also an update how to do that with java 8 btw, take a look.

Comment: Thanks for update, but unfortunately i still have to use java.util.date.