# LocalDateTime unable to parse "June"

Tags: java, java-time

I  had help setting up a function to take two strings and merge them into a date object.
[Java - Take two strings and combine into a single date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725665/java-take-two-strings-and-combine-into-a-single-date-object)

This has been working fine until it tries to parse 1st June, then i get the below error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1st June' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 7
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at Timetable.ClassManager.parseDate(ClassManager.java:201)
    at Timetable.GoogleAPI.loadClasses(GoogleAPI.java:133)
    at Timetable.ClassManager.loadClasses(ClassManager.java:58)
```

The code for the function is

```
public LocalDateTime parseDate(String strDate, String strTime) {
    strTime = strTime + ":00";
    System.out.println("Date: " + strDate);
    System.out.println("Time: " + strTime);
    
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dtfForDate = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, date.getYear())
                                    .appendPattern("d['th']['st']['rd']['nd'] MMM")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    DateTimeFormatter dtfForTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtfForDate)
                                    .atTime(LocalTime.parse(strTime, dtfForTime));
    System.out.println("Local Date Time: " + ldt);
    
    return ldt;
}
```

The two prints give me

```
Date: 1st June

Time: 9:15:00
```

I would need to be able to handle both full month names and month abbreviations, i.e., March was set as Mar, April as Apr.

Comment: well, 1st June isn't a valid format for a Time. that'll be the issue

Comment: You may well just need `MMMM` for full month name. When you parse dates in May it makes no difference because the full month name and the month abbreviation are both `May` in English, so you didn’t discover your bug until you hit into the difference between `Jun` and `June`.

Comment: If you need to accept `Mar`, `Apr`, `May` and `June`, the gold-plated solution is the `appendText(TemporalField, Map<Long, String>)` method already used for ordinal numbers in the last half of the answer. With this you can control accurately which months are written in full and which are abbreviated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following pattern which will cater to both, the three-letter abbreviated month names as well as the full month names:

```
.appendPattern("d['th']['st']['rd']['nd'] [MMMM][MMM]")
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseDate("1st June", "9:15:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("1st Jun", "9:15:00"));
    }

    public static LocalDateTime parseDate(String strDate, String strTime) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dtfForDate = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, date.getYear())
                                        .appendPattern("d['th']['st']['rd']['nd'] [MMMM][MMM]")
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfForTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtfForDate).atTime(LocalTime.parse(strTime, dtfForTime));

        return ldt;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01T09:15
2021-06-01T09:15
```

### Update

This update addresses the following concern raised by Meno Hochschild:

> Personally, I don't like the misuse of optional sections here.
> Negative example: "1th Jun" or "2st Jun" would also be successfully
> parsed but should not.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseDate("1st June", "9:15:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("1st Jun", "9:15:00"));
    }

    public static LocalDateTime parseDate(String strDate, String strTime) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dtfForDate = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, date.getYear())
                                        .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ordinalMap())
                                        .appendPattern(" [MMMM][MMM]")
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfForTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtfForDate).atTime(LocalTime.parse(strTime, dtfForTime));

        return ldt;
    }

    static Map<Long, String> ordinalMap() {
        String[] suffix = { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) 
            map.put((long)i, String.valueOf(i) + suffix[(i > 3 && i < 21) ? 0 : (i % 10)]);
        
        return map;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01T09:15
2021-06-01T09:15
```

**Courtesy:** The logic to build the `Map` is based on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011339/10819573).

Comment: Personally, I don't like the misuse of optional sections here. Negative example: "1th Jun" or "2st Jun" would also be successfully parsed but should not.

Comment: It’s a fair point, @MenoHochschild. I really see it more as a comment on the question than a comment on the answer taking over the same practice from the question. Anyone looking for validation of your negative examples may for example use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369812/5772882) (that question is about formatting, but the formatter I present is fine for parsing too).

Comment: @MenoHochschild - My solution was focused on the main problem: *how to cater to the three-letter abbreviated month names as well as the full month names*. Nonetheless, thanks for the valuable feedback as always. I've added an update to address the concern raised by you.

Comment: @OleV.V. - I was aware of the idea of using a `Map` as posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28614653/10819573). Your solution to build the `Map` is also good. However, I liked more the one which I have referred to in the answer.

Comment: There are many good ways to do it. I agree that the one you picked is very good too. There’s no reason to  hesitate to use it.